# How can I make columns inside a CSS grid row stack on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, css-grid

I´m supposed to change the layout of a web site using two different CSS files without touching the HTML. Hence, I´m wondering if I have a grid with two rows and 5 columns, something like this. Would I be able to have the columns stack on top of each other when screen size gets smaller?

The thing is I want some content to cover the whole width of the top page, and then 5 images beside each other, under that.. When the screen gets smaller i want the content on the top and the images to stack on top of each ocher filling the screen. However, when i make the screen smaller now, the only thing that stacks is the two rows, so the images only get smaller and smaller, still besides each other.

Edit: Sorry for not posting the html, here it is! So the thing in one css file i have a basic css grid with columns. Where all the articles, both the ones that include text and the ones with img, are children of the main - which is the grid container. These end up making a very responsive and flexible layout - without any need for media queries. However, in the second css file, i want the design to create a grid where the photos are lined up on the "bottom half" of your viewscreen, while the text is on the top half. Unless you have a phone etc, where i want the photos to stack, but the "top half" text to be one "column".

```
<main>

        <!--Happy -->

        <article class="text" id="happy">
            <p id="someone">Someone... </p>
            <p class="feeling">might be <span class="word">happy</span></p>
        </article>

        <article class="image" id="happy_img">
            <img src="images/Synne 1x1.jpg" alt="photo of a girl smiling">
        </article>

        <!--excited-->

        <article class="text" id="excited">
            <p class="feeling">might be <span class="word">excited</span></p>
        </article>

        <article class="image" id="excited_img">
            <img src="images/Synne 1x1.jpg" alt="photo of a girl excited">
        </article>

        <!--laughing-->

        <article class="text" id="laughing">
            <p class="feeling">might be <span class="word">laughing</span></p>
        </article>

        <article class="image" id="laughing_img">
            <img src="images/Synne 1x1.jpg" alt="photo of a girl laughing">
        </article>

        <!--confident-->

        <article class="text" id="confident">
            <p class="feeling">might be <span class="word">confident</span></p>
        </article>

        <article class="image" id="confident_img">
            <img src="images/Synne 1x1.jpg" alt="photo of a girl who look confident">
        </article>

        <!--in love-->

        <article class="text" id="love">
            <p class="feeling">might be <span class="word">in love</span></p>
            <p class="afraid">and <span class="word">not</span> afraid to show it</p>
        </article>

        <article class="image" id="love_img">
            <img src="images/Synne 1x1.jpg" alt="photo of a girl who look in love">
        </article>
```

This is the CSS for the first layout,

```
main{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));
grid-gap: 1em;
```

}

This is what I´ve tried with the second, where everything is located where I want it. But the pictures on the 2nd row, lined up in five columns, are not responsive in the sense that they dont stack.

```
main{
display: grid;
grid: 1fr, 1fr / repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
grid-template-areas: "type1 type1 type1 type1 type1"
                     "img1 img2 img3 img4 img5" ;
grid-gap: 1em;
```

}

The ideal responsiveness for smaller viewports would be type 1 grid area to be on top, and each of the img grid areas stacking under it. However, what happens now, is that the type grid-area goes on top, and then the *whole* row, with grid areas img1-5 stacks under it, without the images stacking ontop of each other.

Comment: Making two grid containers, or something like that, would solve the problem. However, i have one grid container which is my <main>, with articles and images as children. In the other design i have only columns, where the text and pictures are ment to be beside each other, and they stack nicely when i make the screen size smaller. The issue is that everything is in the same grid container

Comment: It will surely help if you share your HTML code.

Comment: Please share your HTML. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: I´ve added html and a bit more of explanation now.

Answer (score 0):

I wrap the text article and img article inside a div and gave the id to the div instead so that it goes along with each other. Hope this answer your question.

```css
/* temporary css */
html,
body {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid: 1fr, 1fr / repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1em;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-areas: "type1 type1 type1 type1 type1" "happy excited laughing confident love";
}


/* putting content in place */
#type1 {
  grid-area: type1;
}

#happy {
  grid-area: happy;
}

#excited {
  grid-area: excited;
}

#laughing {
  grid-area: laughing;
}

#confident {
  grid-area: confident;
}

#love {
  grid-area: love;
}


/* temporary css when solving */
article p {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin: 0;
}

article {
  text-align: center;
}


/* condition any article that have the class image */
article img {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 10px;
  /* white-space: pre-wrap; */
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

@media (max-width: 571px) {
  main {
    grid-template-areas: "type1" "happy" "excited" "laughing" "confident" "love";
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <!-- type1 content -->
  <div class="text" id="type1" style="text-align: center;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ad soluta beatae! Ea, omnis qui! Itaque repellat ut doloribus! Error, corporis doloribus doloremque fuga quia temporibus officia voluptatem, quaerat, atque soluta sed ea mollitia alias voluptatibus
      unde eius et impedit reiciendis pariatur eos magni ad. Et quaerat ipsa possimus ad veritatis velit maiores non enim dolores! Ex quibusdam cumque, dolore fugit perferendis excepturi sed accusamus temporibus laborum, dolores iste exercitationem quaerat,
      et a? Eligendi at rerum quia eius quasi ut quisquam. Quis facere exercitationem culpa tempore repellat, expedita consectetur et placeat nemo ea dolorem earum, dicta tempora iste harum voluptate! Aspernatur distinctio tempore eligendi a alias quisquam
      quas ipsa facere aliquam suscipit recusandae odit consectetur, nobis sed optio. Culpa hic magni ipsum nostrum quaerat praesentium iste exercitationem, impedit enim sequi ab necessitatibus labore cum, velit mollitia suscipit fugiat excepturi. Minima
      perferendis et dolorem corrupti aut. Nemo accusamus voluptatum ad exercitationem?</p>
  </div>

  <!--Happy -->
  <div id="happy">
    <article class="text">
      <p id="someone">Someone...</p>
      <p class="feeling">might be <span class="word">red</span></p>
    </article>

    <article class="image" id="happy_img">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507471509451-1d04d60f896d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" " alt="photo of a girl smiling ">
        </article>
        </div>

        <!--excited-->
        <div id="excited ">
            <article class="text ">
                <p class="feeling ">might be <span class="word ">blue</span></p>
            </article>

            <article class="image " id="excited_img ">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515266591878-f93e32bc5937?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=675&q=80 " alt="photo of a girl excited ">
            </article>
        </div>

        <!--laughing-->
        <div id="laughing ">
            <article class="text ">
                <p class="feeling ">might be <span class="word ">green</span></p>
            </article>

            <article class="image " id="laughing_img ">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497250681960-ef046c08a56e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 " alt="photo of a girl laughing ">
            </article>
        </div>

        <!--confident-->
        <div id="confident ">
            <article class="text ">
                <p class="feeling ">might be <span class="word ">purple</span></p>
            </article>

            <article class="image " id="confident_img ">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495287924875-c158d2e8aafc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 " alt="photo of a girl who look confident ">
            </article>
        </div>

        <!--in love-->
        <div id="love ">
            <article class="text ">
                <p class="feeling ">might be <span class="word ">yellow</span></p>
                <p class="afraid ">and <span class="word ">not</span> afraid to show it</p>
            </article>

            <article class="image " id="love_img ">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508808787069-421e7986016e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 " alt="photo of a girl who look in love ">
            </article>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I´ve added the HTML now. Might be easier to help then, as you see, both pictures and text are tangled together as individual children of the grid container.

Comment: I edited the answer. Let me know if that works for you.